Seeking media player that enables user to launch another program with currently displayed file
So, for instance, suppose I'm viewing a series of mp4s, and I notice one that I would like to edit. I would like to be able to press a series of keys to have the media player launch an editor of my choice with that mp4 loaded, ready for editing.
Is there such a beast?

VideoPlayerMpv has some rudimentary scripting capabilities and configurable hotkeys. You can assign to e.g. Ctrl+E (like here: http://tomeko.net/software/VideoPlayerMpv/howto/sorting_files/) script like this:
local filename = GetCurrentFileName()
local editor = "c:\\Program Files\\Avidemux 2.8 VC++ 64bits\\avidemux.exe"

ShellExecute("open", editor, filename, nil, 1)

Script files have to be placed in "scripts" subdirectory. Don't miss double backslashes in the video editor path. You probably would need to stop playback (Enter key by default or Stop() function in script) before file could be saved by the editor if you want to overwrite it.

You should be able to use forward slashes / rather than double backslash.

Poking around some more, I've found pyvidplayer2. It plays videos in Python, has a built-in GUI, and provides various ways of controlling the display of the video being displayed.
